# SQL Server Maintenance Plan Wizard

Tags: ssms

Using SQL Management Studio 2012, when I right-click on an existing Maintenance Plan, and select the "Maintenance Plan Wizard" option from the context menu, what launches is a wizard to create a new maintenance plan.

I need to open the wizard to edit the selected Maintenance Plan.  Please advise as to why this is happening?

Interestingly, when I select the "New Maintenance Plan" option from the context menu, then no wizard pops up at all.

Comment: have you done any research at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the wziard to edit a plan, only to create new ones.

Edit a maintenance plan by just double-clicking it, or right-click -> Modify.

Comment: Thanks...seems there is something very wrong with my system though...when I select Modify from the context menu, nothing happens.  No dialog comes up...nothing.

Comment: Turns out I had Management Tools - Basic installed instead of Management tools - Complete. http://paulgrevink.wordpress.com/2011/05/15/ms-sql-2008-r2-issue-impossible-to-modify-a-maintenance-plan/